# Dynamic create block in magento 2 and send as ajax call response?

Tags: magento2, controllers, ajax, dynamic, response

I want replacement of following in magento 2.x

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/form_login')->setTemplate('persistent/customer/form/login.phtml');

$this->getResponse()->setBody($block->toHtml());
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try following way to create new block inside controller

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Controller\[ControllerName];

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class [YourControllerAction] extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return 
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $block = $this->_view->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login')
                ->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml')
                ->toHtml();

        $this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
    }
}
```

Comment: this statement not get execute I am checking to print log before and after this statement.


     $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login')
    ->setTemplate('Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml')
    ->toHtml();

Comment: Do you initialize $this->resultPageFactory by construct?

Comment: check updated code

Comment: Yes, I have  initialize  your answer seems fine, now there an error in my custom block  as :
Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to \.....\....__construct() must be of the type array, null given.
please may U help.

Thanks for your perfect answer.

Comment: Could you show your custom block code?

Comment: namespace Ipragmatech\Pricenegotiator\Block\Catalog\Product;
 use Ipragmatech\Pricenegotiator\Model\NegotiatorFactory;

class Negotiateprice extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
     protected $_negotiatorFactory;
 protected $_objectManager;
 public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, array $data = [], \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,NegotiatorFactory $negotiatorFactory) {
  parent::__construct ( $context, $data );
  $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
  $this->_negotiatorFactory = $negotiatorFactory;
 }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37848/discussion-between-manish-and-sohel-rana).

Comment: @Manish: whenever you change the __construct function, you need to remove /var/generation folder so Magento 2 can re-created the cache code

Comment: ERROR:  $this->_view->getLayout()->getLayout()
Pleas update :) All other line work fine. Thanks